# How to stop several coroutines running on array of game objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the code below, I am running a coroutine on each element of an array of game objects. How can I stop running the `FadeToForEnemy` coroutine on each game object?

```
 IEnumerator EnemyCycle()    {
while (isRepeating)
{

    for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

        Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
        var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));

    }

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (hdTime);

    for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

        Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
        var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
        var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, true));

    yield return new WaitForSeconds (srTime);

    }
}
}
```

I tried stopping the coroutines in the following but the cycle of fading in and out just continued.

```
public void StopEnemyCycles ()  {
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
    enemies [i].StopAllCoroutines ();
}
StopCoroutine ("EnemyCycle");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have spotted an issue, but not sure if that's what causing the problem.

The second  yield statement: `yield return new WaitForSeconds (srTime);` seems to be before the closed curly brace of the for loop. That is your code is pausing in between elements of the enemies array and starting the coroutine.

I think that after you're stopping all coroutines with `enemies [i].StopAllCoroutines ();` the loop is still going on and starting new ones

Answer (score 0):

You are calling StartCoroutine with one behaviour and then trying to stop it by using StopAllCoroutines on a different behaviour (the enemy). You need to make sure you are starting and stopping the  same object.

Try either calling stop all coroutines in your enemy cycler object or moving the enumerator and the start coroutine call inside your Enemy script.

Answer (score 0):

Normally calling `StopAllCoroutines()` will work but u have to call in the same behaviour in which you started the coroutine.

**Instead of**

```
for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
    enemies [i].StopAllCoroutines ();
}
```

**Use this directly**

```
StopAllCoroutines();
```

That's one way but i would prefer stopping coroutines through `StopCoroutine(Coroutine routine);`
`StartCoroutine(..)` returns Coroutine, so save all Coroutines into an array. and then use StopCoroutine on each of them.

```
List<Coroutine> coroutinesToStop = new List<Coroutine>();
    IEnumerator EnemyCycle()    {
while (isRepeating)
{

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
    var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 0f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, false));
    coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);
}

yield return new WaitForSeconds (hdTime);

for (int j = 0; j < enemies.Length; j++) {

    Enemy currentEnemy = enemies [j];
    var _myMaterial = currentEnemy.GetComponent<Renderer>().material;
    var _currentFade = StartCoroutine(FadeToForEnemy(_myMaterial, 1f, 1f, currentEnemy.gameObject, true));
    coroutinesToStop.Add(_currentFade);
yield return new WaitForSeconds (srTime);

    }
}

public void StopEnemyCycles ()  {
for (int i = 0; i < coroutinesToStop.Count; i++) {
    if(coroutinesToStop != null)
         StopCoroutine (coroutinesToStop[i]);
}
coroutinesToStop.Clear();
StopCoroutine ("EnemyCycle");

}
```

Comment: `StopAllCoroutines();` works, but `StopCoroutine` through `coroutinesToStop` coroutines doesn't work (the fadein and out cycle still continues). I am still at the early stages of my game dev and would most likely be  adding other coroutines that I wouldn't want to stop with the `EnemyCycle` within the object.

Comment: If StopCoroutine is not working then there must be some logical bug in the code like coroutinesToStop is empty, or maybe some other issue. 
I suggest you to play with Coroutines a bit in dummy scene. Check how it works then you may be able to figure out why it's not working. Try StopCoroutine through reference or string based override, also try to stop coroutines running in one script from another script.